# Passing lock ownership

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

With RAII, we have [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock). Those two are explicitly **movable**. RAII objects are "locked" when constructed and "unlocked" when destructed. So, I see absolutely no real reason for forbidding "ownership" to be passed to a different thread. Were it not correct or useful, one could say the same about passing a unique_ptr to another thread.

I would like to do something like:

```cpp
std::scoped_lock lock{mutex};
// Do some stuff.
// Decide to multithread...
auto lambda = [lock = std::move(lock)]
{
  // Do stuff with the lock.
};
std::thread{std::move(lambda)}.detach();
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. I am missing anything? Does this not make sense?
2. I didn't see any mention to not unlocking in a different thread in [cppreference's description of the std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock). So, I would like to know if the standard forbids the code I posted above.

Comment: Use a non-recursive mutex or a semaphore.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am using a non-recursive mutex. I am actually using a std::shared_mutex. Yet, the standard says it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have tagged this `[c++]`.  In Java there two kinds of "lock".  One kind is transferable and the other is not.  The non-transferable kind is often referred to as "primitive lock" or "mutex" ... and it is actually a behavior of all objects!

Comment: @Useless: It is probably a mistake because in terms of "mutexes", people are very much in the stage equivalent to users of "raw pointer". Just like with unique_ptr, I see no reason for not allowing mutex ownership to be transferred. Associating with the thread is actually a hack that is mathematically speaking, wrong, but still... works most of the time. There is a false sensation of "userproofness". This is what the "underlying underdeveloped mechanism" does. Remember: it is not just because you do not see the usefulness that it is "useless". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

You can absolutely move a *lock* from one thread to another so long as the underlying *Lockable* supports it. None of the standard library mutexes do support it, though.

---

> So, I see absolutely no real reason for forbidding "ownership" to be passed to a different thread.

Neither do I, in principle, with a couple of caveats:

1. It could be UB even if it makes sense, if the standard is conservative, or restrictive, or wants to allow implementations space for some cunning platform specific optimization
2. Some specific mutex types, like recursive mutexes, may need to store the current thread ID and would thus be unable to cope with this use case.

All that said, we can check the standard:

> [`[thread.req.lockable.general]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.lockable#def:execution_agent) In general

> 1/ An execution agent is an entity such as a thread that may perform work in parallel with other execution agents.

> [Note 1: Implementations or users can introduce other kinds of agents such as processes or thread-pool tasks.
> — end note]

> [Note 2: Some lockable objects are “agent oblivious” in that they work for any execution agent model because they do not determine or store the agent's ID (e.g., an ordinary spin lock).
> — end note]

So, it certainly sounds like we're free to use our own "execution agent" abstraction, and at least some lockable types should work fine as our abstraction moves from one thread to another.

Unfortunately none of the standard mutex types are in this category: they all specify that they must be unlocked by the thread that "owns" the mutex, the only way of owning a mutex is to lock it, and no mechanism for transferring ownership is described.

However, you can write your own *Cpp17Lockable* type, based on a semaphore, or a spinlock, or anything else that doesn't explicitly prohibit this, and consider yourself officially blessed by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

> With RAII, we have [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock). Those two are explicitly **movable**. RAII objects are "locked" when constructed and "unlocked" when destructed. So, I see absolutely no real reason for forbidding "ownership" to be passed to a different thread.

Yes, as far as `std::unique_lock` and `std::scoped_lock` are concerned, it is no problem to move the ownership to another thread. That's because these classes [focus on one task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) – RAII for the lock.

These classes know absolutely nothing about how a mutex operates. All they require is that the wrapped object (such as a mutex) is "[(Basic)Lockable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Lockable)" – that it has member functions `lock()` and `unlock()` and in some cases `try_lock()`. The lock classes make sure that a call to `lock()` is matched by a call to `unlock()` and that a call to `try_lock()` that returns `true` is matched by a call to `unlock()`. These classes do not care what the effects of these functions are; all that matters is that `unlock()` is called when required.

Instead of looking at the RAII wrapper, you should look at what is being wrapped. If you are wrapping [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), then the following applies.

> A calling thread *owns* a `mutex` from the time that it successfully calls either `lock` or `try_lock` until it calls `unlock`.

This is why you cannot transfer ownership of a `std::mutex` to another thread. The thread that locked the `std::mutex` will own the mutex until **it** calls `unlock`. Not merely until `unlock` is called (by someone), but until that particular thread calls `unlock`. When using `std::mutex`, this task cannot be delegated to another thread.

Another Lockable might behave differently and allow ownership to be transferred across threads, but `std::mutex` does not.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason for "don't do this" is, it's unconventional. If you ever expect other programmers to read your code—if you ever expect to collaborate with them, or if you ever ask another programmer for help—then you'll have better luck if everybody speaks the same language.

"Mutex" isn't just the name of a type in some programming language. It's the name of a [*design pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern). If you use something called "mutex" in your code, then everybody who sees it will immediately expect you to use it in a certain way.* They'll be confused and frustrated if you defy their expectations. They won't enjoy working with you or helping you.

There's a different name for the thing that you want to do. It's called [*binary semaphore*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). It acts almost exactly like a mutex except, if you lock it in one thread and unlock it in another, nobody will raise an eyebrow.

---

* "Mutex" says, "I'm just going to access some shared data here, and I'm going to be as quick about it as I can."
"Semaphore" says, "[Hey! Hold my beer, and watch this](https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/)."

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the previous answers: the reason `unlock` must be called from the thread that `lock` was called from is because `pthread_mutex_unlock` or its Windows equivalent have this constraint. In the end, it's really part of the definition of a mutex.