# Is it legal to lock the std::mutex in main thread and then unlock in the child thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Is it ***legal*** to lock the std::mutex in main thread and then unlock in the child thread.
Here is a demo [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/5d65sY8aK), which ***seems*** work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
 
 int main()
 {
    std::mutex mtx;

    mtx.lock();

    std::thread([&](){mtx.unlock();}).join();

    std::thread([&](){mtx.lock();}).join();
 }
```

Comment: I think it is UB. You are trying to unlock mutex that is not currently locked by the calling thread.

Comment: [Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock): The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Your question may already be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487357/how-stdmutex-got-unlocked-in-different-thread  Which says that **no** it's not legal.

Comment: I agree that [How std::mutex got unlocked in different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487357/how-stdmutex-got-unlocked-in-different-thread) looks like a duplicate, although your example code is simpler and more focused.

Comment: See also: [Passing Lock Ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77463430/801894)

Comment: Even if it was legal, it would be very strange. A mutex lock is like a door protecting entry into a room , or for C++  [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) . Now ask yourself why would you move a door to a different room ? So far in over 20 years of designing multithreaded code I've never needed this.

Comment: I once spent HOURS trying to find a mutex unlock. The mutex was locked in the serial driver and could have been unlocked in the modem code that sat atop it or any or the other dozen packages that used a serial port. You don't want to have to debug code like that when you could be spending time with the kids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the patterns I use most to let threads wait for each other that does not require locks to be passed around. (This pattern is more powerful when instead of a bool you use a state enum).
Otherwise you can also have a look at std::latch/std::barrier

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    
    // despite its name a condition variable is more of an interthread signal
    // signalling something has changed that is worth checking
    std::condition_variable cv;     

    bool thread1_finished{ false };

    std::thread thread1{ [&]
    {
        std::cout << "thread 1 doing stuff\n";
        std::scoped_lock lock{mtx};
        thread1_finished = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }};

    std::thread thread2{ [&]
    {
        // wait for thread 1 to finish
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{mtx};
            // this is not a busy wait.
            // thread will go to sleep until cv is signalled
            // and then it will check the predicate
            cv.wait(lock, [&] { return thread1_finished; });
        }

        std::cout << "thread 2 doing stuff\n";
    }};

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    
    return 1;
}
```